# Unit Testing (Android) - Common scenarios to test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

I have seen different UT examples over the intent but could not find a practical way to integrate UT for my app.

Please consider this simple activity, which can read a JSON feed and post data.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   String dataArray;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   public void onCreate() {
        //Get json data from the server
        getAPIdata();
   }

    /** get data json from the server */
    public getAPIdata(Server Response){
        //Parse the json output
        //Validate 
        //populate data array
        return dataArray;
    }


    /** use populated data array and display */
    public setListView(dataArray){
        //use the data array and set a list view to display the results

    }


    /** post data to create a record */
    public postDataToServer(Parameters){
        //validate input data
        //send a post request to the server
        //if success, print a success message on the screen
        //else print the error
    }


}
```

This is the structure I have mostly in my Android application. I don't have much business logic.

Let me summarize again.

1. Retrieve JSON and display results
2. Form input validation
3. POST data into the API to create/edit records

So now you can see this application is handling mostly CRUD operations. My question is you guys is:

How can I make use of UT in this application? (Or UT is not required here as I don't have much business logic?)

Any practical suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step1: separation of concerns. An activity is not supposed to manage downloading json data. Split up logic into different classes where appropriate

Comment: actually I have it in a separate class as u said. Didn't post the full code as it will be very long

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have to read JSON feed and show the results (or something) in this activity, I would write integration tests to test your business logic, server communication, JSON parser etc and an instrumented test to test your Activity directly.

You can see some examples using Espresso framework to test your UI in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) and also use JUnit framework to write your integration tests.